# Scribus export to PDF resulting in missing image

Tags: pdf, export, png, scribus

I have to realize my first poster and decided to use (and learn) Scribus as well as Inkscape and GIMP). I am making progress with these softwares and was beginning to be happy with my poster template when I wanted to print it to check colors. I therefore saved my file as PDF and realised that my main picture was not exported at all. I have no errors (only a warning about transparency: ) and the picture shows in Scribus and is properly linked in the Image manager.

[image: warning]
[image: manager]

I tried to export to play with the option of PDF export (i.e. image compression, maximum resolution, pdf compatibility etc..). I also tried to open my file with different viewers and even Inkscape but image is definitely missing. I search in the forums but could not find any solution.

Image was created in GIMP [image: properties].

I am new to asking question on this graphic design forum so let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: I tried inserting a linked PNG into Scribus, and exporting as PDF, but couln't replicate the issue. PDF output was as expected. Perhaps check you are using the latest stable version of Scribus.

Comment: I have other PNG (logos) which work fine. I have only the issue with my main figure. I am not sure if I can join a file here, it would be easier.

Comment: In the properties palette you might have set the image to "do not print"... if it's not the case, you should probably try to create a "demo" document that shows the issue. if you can replicate it there , please share that document with us. if you cannot, remove the image from the document and insert it again... it should work then.

Comment: I checked the properties of the image but could not find the option "do not print". Could you provide me with the link via menu (I am using windows).  Also would you tell me how to do this demo document? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are doing very well for a new member. Welcome to Graphic Design.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a.l.e, I found the issue. A small button in the image properties hindering the object export was clicked. I unclicked it and now everything works fine (I had to scroll down to see this button appear).

[image: icon]

Comment: Thank you for sharing honestly this surprising answer/solution. Since you had never seen this button before, it was of course not you who opted to not-print your main illustration. Why would you? Please note that in Scribus (and possibly GIMP) there is a "new user random challenger" playing such little tricks, to help you learning about all the awesome features. After you have used Scribus for 120 hours, those little pranks will stop happening. There is a hack where you can in return trick Scribus and up your usage-hours above 120 but I have not found details yet.

Comment: And a.l.e you did it again, well done. I was guessing around problems with transparency and type/version of PDF and you just had the nerve to ask the user "did you maybe opt out of printing?" (where the answer would be "thuu, of course not") and you got it. Write an answer, even late, and I will click it. And happy Scribing to us all, or what is the verb for using Scribus?...

Comment: Thanks Martin for the tip about this random challenger beginner which made me laugh hard (and for the welcome words), and a.l.e. same here, write an answer and I will accept it :)